# Safely fix coordinate precision without causing intersections/gaps between feature collections

Tags: java, turf

This might be a rather broad question because I am not sure if it points to a specific technology or tool.

I am working on a dataset that has mixed precision coordinates and the polygons drawn have some intersections and gaps at a centimetric or even a millimetric level. Truncation and rounding does not seem to do the trick because it arbitrarily moves a point in the space.

Is it possible to make sure that these features fit in perfectly without gaps and intersections? I am willing to work on a precision of 6 digits after decimal point.

Techs I use:

- Java
- TurfJS for UI

Comment: Terms to help you find something: Snap to grid, topological generalisation or simplification, topologically aware. Try mapshaper.

Comment: Assuring that datasets are mutually exclusive and exhaustively complete is a nontrivial task. To code that from scratch in Java to meet just a few of the ugly cases available might exhaust your time budget.

Comment: Picture of what you have and would like to achieve would help.